# What should I look for in good headphones?

Tags: headphones

I'm in the search of the best headphones to fit my needs. I hope somebody will help me because I try and I try but I haven't found the exact real headphones I want.

I want to use them to mostly listen to a tablet or an iphone at office. 
I have already tried several headphones :

**AKG 271 Studio** : really flat, useful for recording but the impedance is too high to use it on a mp3 player. I have kept it for use in my studio on a Fast Track Pro.

**Q-Jays** : excellent sound, very small, good impedance for my needs but I don't always like intra-auricular headphones, I would prefer closed headphones with the same sound !

**ATH-ESW9** : really nice, comfortable, with a lot of bass (too much maybe for me), but too expensive to let in my office (and semi opened so noisy) :)

**ATH-AD700** : way too big, nice sound but they make too much noise outside (opened headphones)

**Koss Portasound** : too much bass...

I want a clear sound, not too much bass, low impedance to be able to listen high volume on a mp3 player, comfortable, not too big not too small closed headphones for less than $200

Any ideas ? (not Sennheiser please)
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this would be considered off-topic or not. This site is not a shopping recommendation site. Read the FAQ (http://avp.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: I'm sorry : at first i wanted to ask for a good pair of headphones for studio but as my AKG 271 is really good with my Fast Track, i'm now in search for a very good everyday pair of headphones. I hoped people using headphones for music production (like me) could help me

Comment: Well, it hasn't been closed, so you can assume it's okay.

Comment: Good choice going for just a good pair of every day headphones. Studio headphones should be only used in the studio. :)

Comment: This question is about audio, but not necessarily audio production. Meta discussion [here](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want closed headphones, the Sony MDR-7506 are a great value ($99), though they lean toward the larger side.  Yes they're sometimes used in the studio, but I've liked them as a field product as well.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i have bought them for a quite low price and they completely fit my needs ..  Probably good enough for some studio works, not too big and closed enough for listening to good music in the office.. I have read bad critics of them but i really like them though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Beyerdynamic dt 115 , all time classic , pretty balanced (real) sound (noyhing exaggerated) and not fatiguing , mainly for studio use , close format for the sound not to escape or come in and nice head fit . Check them out!